# How to add Admob in html css3 jquery base android application

Tags: android, jquery, html, web-applications, admob

I made an app in html5, css3 and with jquery then i convert it in apk via intel sdk now i want to add admob on it. Anyone know best way that how i can add admob in html site.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt this is possible.